# Изменение множества свойств элементов в MVVM

Tags: wpf, .net

Пишу проект с шаблоном MVVM. В проекте несколько страниц, на которых есть кнопки смены состояния. От состояния (on/off) зависит некоторое содержимое, например цвета текста, сам текст, цвет индикаторов и т д.
Вопрос в следующем: как с применением паттерна MVVM правильно производить эти изменения. Я так понимаю, что нужно внутри VM реализовать свойства, к которым будут привязаны элементы и по команде внутри VM их менять.

Но что делать, если на одной странице таких элементов много и они однотипные, можно ли как-то упростить задачу?

Вот пример:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton Command="{Binding Command}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Row="1"
               Foreground="{Binding TextColor}"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

При этом измененное состояние нужно сохранять.

Comment: Создайте UserControl, задайте ему указанный вид и привяжите все к DependencyProperty, тогда ваш код будет выглядеть примерно как `<uc:MyControll Color="Red" Text="Hello!!"...>`.

Comment: Если у вас текст, цвет и картинка зависит только от состояния, то я бы, как написали выше сделал UserControl который бы все эти изменения проделывал сам, в зависимости от состояния кнопки, а состояние кнопки сделал бы свойством к которому можно прибиндит bool. У вас, в этом случае, модель будет представлять собой обычную коллекцию булевых значений, а вся логика изменений в контролах. Или у вас текст и все остальное зависит не только от состояния кнопки, но еще и от других, внешних, параметров?

Comment: @АлексейЛосев, да, текст и некоторые индикаторы могут меняться в зависимости от состояния внутри модели

Comment: Тогда надо понимать реализуемую логику. Вашу разметку вынести в UserControl, дальше, если есть возможность (а она скорее всего есть) сделать ItemsControl в ItesSource которого передать коллекцию моделей, а в качестве DataTempalte указать свежесозданный UserControl. Разберетесь? Или показать пример?

Comment: @АлексейЛосев, да, разберусь, спасибо. Просто всегда старался избегать создания пользовательских контролов. Наверное зря